# ¿Qué es el module-info de java y para qué se utiliza?

Tags: java, java-9

Hace tiempo que no volvía a tocar Java y al actualizar a la ultima versión tanto del entorno (Eclipse) como del JDK, a la versión 12, me pregunta al crear un proyecto si quiero crear un nuevo **module-info** algo que nunca antes me habían preguntado.

Supongo que esta opción vendrá de las últimas actualizaciones en Java pero no se exactamente que es ni para que se utiliza.

He buscado si alguien había preguntado algo similar pero no logro encontrarlo por eso me animé a preguntarlo yo.
Siento si la pregunta es un poco "tonta" pero no me lo quito de la cabeza. 
¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Después de buscar bibliografía por mi universidad encontré la respuesta a la pregunta sobre qué son los módulos y cual es su utilidad.

Para ello primero hay que entender que es una librería, la cual antes de java-9, era la única opción para la funcionalidad que ofrece el módulo.

**¿Qué es una librería?**

Una librería es un conjunto de clases compiladas y comprimidas bajo un mismo fichero, normalmente con extensión `.jar`

Con esto conseguimos añadir funcionalidad a nuestro proyecto reutilizando código. 
Supongamos que nuestra aplicación tiene que crear informes en pdf, para ello en vez de realizar codigo desde cero podemos utilizar por ejemplo la librería *`apache fop`*, para así de forma rápida añadir esta funcionalidad que ya estaba diseñada por otro desarrollador y en la que nos podemos apoyar.

Ahora bien, **¿Qué es un módulo y para qué se utiliza?**

Después de haber explicado que es una librería nos es más fácil explicar que es un módulo.
A partir de Java-9 las librerías empiezan a perder fuerza frente a la arquitectura modular. Las librerías deberían ser convertidas en módulos para aclarar cuales son sus dependencias para funcionar y que funcionalidades ofrecen.

Un tipo especial de módulo son los módulos automáticos. Son aquellas librerías que se convierten de manera automática en módulos. Como no contienen fichero descriptor (`module-info.java`), se registran con el mismo nombre de la librería, es decir, `nombreDelFichero.jar` (Donde el .jar, obviamente, no será parte del nombre) y exportarán todos sus paquetes con todas sus clases. Para que una librería se convierta en módulo debe estar referenciada en el `module-path` del entorno.

Es por eso que en java-9 tenemos dos rutas importantes:

`Class Path` (forma clásica): ruta donde se buscarán las clases en tiempo de compilación o ejecución, esta ruta apunta a librerías `.jar` o directorios.

`Module path`: ruta donde se buscarán los módulos en tiempo de compilación o ejecución.

Finalmente, **¿Para qué sirve el module-info.java?**

Para exportar o importar paquetes, este fichero descriptor nos será de mucha utilidad para saber que exportamos o bien que importamos.

*Exportación:*

> Ejemplo de fichero module-info.java

```
module EjemploStackOverflow {
exports es.stack.ejemploStack1;
}
```

El código anterior define el módulo `EjemploStackOverflow` donde se exportan las clases ubicadas en el paquete es.stack.ejemploStack1.

*Importación:*

> Ejemplo de fichero module-info.java

```
module NuevoEjemplo {
requires EjemploStackOverflow;
}
```

Si nos fijamos, ahora el fichero indica que necesitamos el módulo `EjemploStackOverflow`.

Para responder a mi pregunta he utilizado el libro Java 9 de Roberto Montero Miguel de mi facultad. Así ha podido ser más fácil entender el funcionamiento de los módulos.