# Error de librerias

Tags: java, java-swing, java-ee

Estoy haciendo una práctica de Procesador de Lenguajes y necesito usar un objeto Document, pero al intentar importar las librerias:

```
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
```

Me da el error:

```
 The type javax.swing.text.BadLocationException is not
 accessibleJava(16778666)
```

en ambas.

Que puedo hacer?

Comment: ¿Estás trabajando con Eclipse?

Comment: No entiendo muy bien **cuándo** ocurre el error. Dices que *al querer importar las librerías*. ¿Eso que significa, que pones `import ....`  y salta el error?  No lo entiendo. Si el error salta en una línea de código concreta, agrega esa línea de código a la pregunta.

Comment: Creo que estás usando los módulos de Java. Si tienes un fichero module-info.java en tu proyecto, quítalo. Mira más información en https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/282078/qu%C3%A9-es-el-module-info-de-java-y-para-qu%C3%A9-se-utiliza